# How to remove duplicate mark from my question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

How can I get the duplicate mark removed from my question?

I feel this is carelessly marked, since the duplicate given doesn't solve anything / even over-complicates the problem / leads to another duplicate.

This is the link to my question : [How to write enum with # character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232413/how-to-write-enum-with-character)

If I am wrong, please say so.

This is really important since I believe duplicate mark will likely make my question ignored and left unanswered.

Comment: I won't speak for whether the duplicate is correct. But the whole point of the marking a question duplicate is to tell everybody to ignore it so they can make better use of their time.

Comment: @Mysticial Why tell people to ignore a certain question if there's still no legitimate answer given? I still don't get it. Please elaborate

Comment: It's a duplicate as you're trying to name enums with characters that are not allowed, which is what the other question is about. The answer for that question also goes for your question

Comment: @MosesAprico Because there are thousands of new questions a day. That's too many for the community to handle. Marking duplicates is one of many ways to reduce the redundant work.

Comment: @user1066946 have you read my given link on my question post? The link said that `[Description("C#")]` will work. But it's not.

Comment: @MosesAprico [This is the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1415146/1066946), which is true for your question.

Comment: Okay, even if I still feel something is not right, but I somehow feel that I should accept it. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Ok, @Mysticial ... but, what if I don't agree with duplicate mark? I ask question about `NSDictionary` in `iOS` and my question is marked as duplicate with solution in `C#` - I don't understand why? How I can complain on this? See the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696556/how-to-filter-nsdictionary-by-value-and-create-new-nsdictionary-from-that/30697001#30697001).

Comment: @new2ios I have no idea what you're talking about. That question is not marked as a duplicate of anything. Speaking more generally, when people whine about their question getting closed, it's usually for one of these reasons: 1) Their question is legit, but they failed to communicate it to everyone else. So it gets misinterpreted and closed. (i.e. should be closed as "Unclear what you're asking") 2) They don't understand the site rules. What they think is on-topic really isn't. 3) They feel entitled.

Comment: Ok, sorry @Mysticial - I mean "...This question may already have an answer here:..". This remark is not relevant to the question (in my point of view). Otherwise I agree with what you say.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason that we close questions is precisely that we don't want them answered. In the case of a duplicate closure, we want all the information to end up in one place -- under the original (or best) question. Duplicate closure is also to *help* you, though: the solution to your problem was already posted, and the close voters are just pointing you to it.

If your question has been closed as a duplicate, but the answers to the other question don't solve your problem, edit your question to explain exactly why. Be sure to actually try to use the information in the other answers. Don't just write "That obviously is different"; take some time and try to understand why expert users decided to help you by pointing you to an existing post.

If you truly can't resolve your problem after that, then add the details of what you took away  from that post, and what you still have trouble with. (A question along the lines of "I read this other SO question but I don't understand the answer because X, Y, and Z" usually makes a good new post.) Your question will be put into the reopen review queue, where voters will see that it's no longer a duplicate and can reopen it.

Further reading: [gnat's stellar answer to "Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/159251) on Meta.SE

Comment: So, you just have to edit the question and somebody will review the fact that it was marked as duplicate? I do find it unintuitive there's not a button to "object to marking as duplicate" to enable the user to feel that something is actually happening