# How to react to a wrong duplicate closure (not my question) when the question has been deleted

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm unsure how (and if) to react, and I haven't found a complete answer here:

- [How to remove duplicate mark from my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260607/how-to-remove-duplicate-mark-from-my-question)
- [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not)
- [What can I do if I believe that my question was wrongly marked as a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253521/what-can-i-do-if-i-believe-that-my-question-was-wrongly-marked-as-a-duplicate)
- [How should we handle a wrong duplicate link?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364469/how-should-we-handle-a-wrong-duplicate-link)
- [question incorrectly marked as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195516/question-incorrectly-marked-as-duplicate)
- [Removing wrong duplicate flag when there is a correct duplicate flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300952/removing-wrong-duplicate-flag-when-there-is-a-correct-duplicate-flag)
- [Incorrect/wrong duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/incorrect-wrong-duplicate-question)

as most of this boils down to:

- "improve the question" (but I'm the potential answerer, and not the OP), or
- "contact the closer" (I tried in a comment, but did not get any response; I did not try in a chat), or
- "contact a moderator" (but the question was deleted, and I cannot access the "flag" link)

---

Here's the full story:

1. I came upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808771/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-all-combination-of-group-of-strings) on Stack Overflow (note: you cannot see it now unless you have 10k rep).
2. I wrote an answer for it.
3. As I was about to post it, I noted the question got closed as a duplicate in the meantime, so I thought:

   > Well, a pity. But let's see how it was solved in the duplicate - maybe I can post my answer there, if no one came with such a solution yet.
4. Upon visiting this [supposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string), I realized it's not really (as far as I understand) a duplicate, although it indeed is related.

   I believe it not to be a duplicate because it's really not trivial to deduce the answer to the one from the other. It is so because the scope of the supposed duplicate is far narrower:

   - the OP asked about generic lists of objects (and only gave strings as an example), while the supposed duplicate deals with strings only,
   - the OP asked about *combinatations + permutations*, while the supposed duplicate deals with permutations only.

   Note that I'm not trying to say that the question was written perfectly. It was far from perfect, and I guess it could be improved significantly.

   Note that I'm also not trying to say there's no duplicate to the original question out there. But I wasn't able to find it in short time, and - as far as I understand - the duplicate link *should* point to a question that is about essentially the same problem (or a problem trivially deducible from it), and here it doesn't (again, it's as far as I understand - please, prove me wrong if possible).
5. So, upon searching a bit, I decided to follow [this advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364471/2032415), and I left a comment on the question (essentially saying "Please, explain.") for the gold-badge holder that closed the question (I'm unsure whether he got notified about it, though). I also upvoted the question to show that I considered it good enough.

   I didn't flag for moderator attention because I was afraid it will be too heavy artillery yet (note that some comments about this topic hinted I could do it, while [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300954/2032415) says I shouldn't do it, and it's hard to disagree with it).
6. When I checked on the question after a while, it turned out it was deleted, and I cannot flag it for moderator attention.

   I don't know who deleted it (maybe it was the OP, who deleted it under peer pressure, and maybe it was someone else).

Now, I'm writing all this *not only* because I have an answer ready, but *primarily* because it just seems a shame that a question which looked quite fair got closed like that, especially when I have seen many "less-valuable" questions being answered or even upvoted.

---

**To sum up**, I'd like to know *how* I should react in such cases. Or maybe I should *not* react when it's not my question, and *not* try to (kind of) act on behalf of the OP? (note that the OP is a 1-rep user so he'll probably not raise the issue himself)

Comment: Sounds like you are in an excellent position to construct a [self-answered Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Just make sure your question is of sufficient quality, and your answer is not a duplicate. I suggest explaining in the question why the related question is inadequate.

Comment: The op deleted the question himself. I didn't check in detail, but at least some of the answers in the duplicate seem to deal with arrays of strings.

Comment: @jpp Thanks, I also wondered about that but wasn't sure if it'd be OK to post a question that is not really my question (so if someone e.g. asks for more specifics, I cannot really give them). I also wasn't sure whether I should somehow reference the original author or not, so I thought it'd be best to somehow get the original question answered.

Comment: @BDL Thanks for letting me know. As for the single answer to the question, I believe it does not really answer the question at all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A deleted question is... well... deleted. This means it can't get changed in any way, except by either undeleting it or involving a moderator.

If the OP of a question has deleted the question, there's very little you can do. You can try and get it undeleted, but that would require multiple >10K users to agree with you, and undeleting against the author's wishes is generally not something we do.

The best thing you can do if a question you have an answer on gets deleted is just move on. There's very little else to do. Honestly, removing the duplicate mark of a deleted question that can't be found normally is a waste of time.

In certain situations, you can repost the question and answer it yourself, but note that if you're citing the question, attribution is required, even though the question is deleted. It's often better to fully write your own question in that case.

Comment: All good advice. Do you have a reference for `if you're citing the question, attribution is required`? Although I would *recommend* this, I don't see why it should be a *requirement*. I've never heard of any issues regarding plagiarized questions.

Comment: @jpp Not one specific to this situation, but the [Attribution Required blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) covers it. Stack Overflow content always requires attribution when shared, even if you share it on Stack Overflow itself, as it's CC BY SA licensed.

Comment: Erik, thanks for your answer! I definitely agree that opening the question against the author's wishes is not a good idea (it might have been misleading that I tagged the question as "reopen-closed", but at the time of writing I wasn't sure who deleted it). And I understand now that there's no point in doing anything more until the question remains deleted. I'm considering contacting the OP now through chat, and asking him whether he solved the problem. Maybe he won't even read my message, but it really would be nice to get the solution across to him, if he hadn't solved the problem yet.

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski, As a general rule, it's a good idea to answer a *question* rather than a *person*. SO is fundamentally a Q&A site rather than a help-desk. If you think your answer can help the wider community and is not a duplicate, nor can it be placed in another Q&A, you are *encouraged* to write a self-answered Q&A.

Comment: Note: "can't get changed in any way" is inaccurate. For deleted posts that are not locked (posts deleted as spam or rude/abusive are automatically locked when deleted): users with >10k rep can edit the post while it's deleted. In addition, the OP can also edit such deleted answers and can edit such deleted questions, under some, but not all, conditions.

Comment: One more question: if (for some reason) the "duplicate" flag were removed from this closed question, would the OP get notified about it? I'm asking just out of curiosity because - if he got notified - he could (theoretically, probably not) undelete the question himself in hope of getting some valid answers.

Comment: @jpp: I doubt the question has enough value to the community that it'd be worth a self-answered Q&A. After all, it was about generating [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) subsets, which results in a lot of elements very quickly so it makes sense only for a few elements. It was interesting, though :)

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski, You might be right. But if *you* found it interesting, I'd wager *others* might too. Don't underestimate the range of topics the SO user-base might find interesting :)

Comment: Self answered QA is a lot harder, you have to show research effort (possibly including a made up MVCE), the OP might also be penalized for looking like they were posting an overly localized question just for the sake of answering it. SO is pretty harsh on selfie QA, there's been a few success stories but I've seen far more disappointing cases where a well meaning OP just gets downvotes/close votes/delete votes/roomba'd in exchange for their time. Probably better off just making a blog post if it's worth time time writing it.

Comment: @jrh, "Be the change you wish to see" is an apt quote here. I've seen (and suffered) this "harsh on selfie Q&A" behaviour too, but choose to ignore it. SO is bigger than a few "rep-policemen" who choose to see a question as a rep-hunt.

Comment: @jpp your commitment to what this site hoped to be is admirable. I think SO provides the tools to create good content for snippets and documenting obscure features that would generally be too small for a blog (and also anonymously, without the hosting costs / headaches). I'd recommend keeping an archive of your content (though as a 10k+ user you won't lose it and have to go fishing for it through data dumps / archive.org like I would). While SO is big it only takes the roomba to delete your stuff. I hope it works out well for you, and thanks for taking the time to share your knowledge.

Comment: @jpp [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25683642/revisions); the original question posted was very small (see revision history), got heavily downvoted until the OP made a meta post and it eventually recovered after adding some code. Personally I would be very willing and able to provide "How do I do X", A: "Here's how" selfie Q/A, but I guess I'm just not interested in making a fake "what I tried" section. Officially "How Do I" questions are acceptable but SO users are divided on this and tend to see them as "zero effort homework dumps".

Comment: Even though I know why it's like this, I just can't accept that a selfie Q/A should ever get treated like a "zero effort homework dump", it's honestly a disrespectful way to treat *contributors* and something is very broken here if that happens. I realize that reviewers review questions independently of answers (and in most cases that is totally fair) but I think this model is very flawed for self-answered Q/A; maybe have a different review UI or put them in a different queue altogether, or heck put them on a different site (I liked the idea of Docs).